# Choosing balls: 20 balls, 4 different types (yel,black,green,blue).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There're 20 balls, 4 different types (yel,black,green,blue).

We bought 5 balls from each type: 5 yellow, 5 black, 5 green, 5 blue.

How many options can we divide them to 7 students (and **it could be** that no one got any of the balls) and there is significance to the type of the balls.

Well, I thought somewhere towards:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 20$

Which will be $D(7,20) = C(26,6)$ options. but there's the thing that we divided the balls to 4 types, and 5 balls to each type. so there's much more to it. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you know how to count the number of ways to distribute 20 uncolored balls. Could you just distribute the yellow ones? Then once you do that, can you distribute the black ones? Etc.

Comment: @SE318: That's what I thought. so I can write $D(7,5) * 4$ and that is the answer?

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation D(n,r) but assuming it is the number of ways to choose with repetition, then yes.

Comment: @SE318 $D(7,5) = C(7+5-1,7-1) = C(11,6)$

Comment: Then yeah. That is a formula for multi choose. I personally use $\left(\binom{n}r\right)$ but it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_k$ be the number of yellow balls obtained by the $k$th student.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 5$$
The number of ways to distribute the yellow balls is the number of ways to place six addition signs in a row of five ones, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 6}{6} = \binom{11}{6}$$
since we must choose which six of the eleven symbols (five ones and six addition signs) will be addition signs.  By symmetry, we have the same number of choices for each of the other colors.  Hence, the number of ways of distributing the $20$ balls to the seven students is $$\binom{11}{6}^4$$